# Custom button for finish and redirect after all upload is done in Blueimp jQuery File Upload

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, upload, blueimp, jquery-file-upload

I want to add a custom button on on jquery-file-upload API plugin . when all files uploaded then this button is enable and is there is no files or there is no uploaded files then button is remain disable.
i want a button so when upload is done then only user can click on finish button otherwise it remain disable.

Please help !! :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this, add your custom button inside your fileupload html and make it disabled :

```
<div class="span7">
                    <span class="fileinput-button ufloat">
                        <span class="icon icon-plus"></span>
                        <span class="upload_txt">choose file to upload</span>
                        <input type="file" multiple="multiple" size="1"/>
                    </span>
                    <button type="submit" id="uploadBtn" class="btn-primary start">
                        <i class="icon icon-upload"></i>
                        <span>Upload</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="reset" id="cancelBtn" class="btn-primary cancel">
                        <i class="icon icon-ban-circle"></i>
                        <span>cancel</span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Adding your custom button -->
                    <button id="customBtn" disabled="true"></button>
                </div>
```

and in your main.js add this in your done function :

```
$('#fileuploadbasic').fileupload({
         done: function{
                  var filess= data.files[0];
            var filenam = filess.name;
            data.context.text('');
            $(data.context).append('<td class="name" colspan="6">'+filenam+' uploaded Success</td>');

// after finish upload and there are no other files to upload make
// make custom button enabled
if( $('tbody tr.template-upload td.start').length == 0) {
    $('#customBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
}
         }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) done option is not work with it i have already tried this the problems with this option is it will call every time when upload is done and after enable custom button it will not disable if we delete all files or cancel upload . if you have another solution for that please post here